# Pivot over a range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I havea table like following,

[image]

How to write a query to get this

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: May I point out that your first `A` seems to count only in `10-40` and not `40-60`. The second range should probably be `41-60`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify what database product you are using but you should be able to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression in any database to get the result:

```
select subject,
  sum(case when marks > 10 and marks <= 40 then 1 else 0 end) Range10_40,
  sum(case when marks > 40 and marks <= 60 then 1 else 0 end) Range40_60
from yt
group by subject;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17fec/6)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

For Mysql

```
 SELECT 
    subject, 
    sum(if(marks between 10 and 40, 1, 0)) as '(10-40)',
    sum(if(marks between 40 and 60, 1, 0)) as '(40-60)'
 FROM 
    tbl
 GROUP BY 
    subject
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6193/2)**

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could work...

```
SELECT t.`subject`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subject` as t2 WHERE t2.`range` BETWEEN (10 AND 40) AND t2.`subject` = t.`subject`) as `range1040`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subject` as t2 WHERE t2.`range` BETWEEN (40 AND 60) AND t2.`subject` = t.`subject`) as `range4060`
FROM `table` as t
GROUP BY t.`subject`
ORDER BY t.`subject`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select subject, sum(case when marks between 10 and 40 then 1 else 0) as oneToFourty, 
    sum(case when marks between 40 and 60 then 1 else 0) as fourtyToSixty
from table
    group by subject
```

Your range seems a bit strange (overlaps) so I'll leave the finer detail to you.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
select subject, 
sum(case when marks between 10 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as Range1, 
sum(case when marks between 40 and 60 then 1 else 0 end) as Range2
from _Scores
group by subject
```

This works because the case statement will check every row, returning to Range1 if the numbers match, 0 if not. Same thign with Range2. The the sum statement sums the ones and zeros to give you counts of each.